# Embed javascript in html attributes

Tags: javascript, html

I have following code,

```
<li>
  <button id="javascript:var id_btn1 = 'id' + Math.random().toString(16).slice(2);" 
      class="btn btn-primary helpful">
    <i class="fa fa-thumbs-up"></i>
    Helpful
    <p id="javascript:var id_count1 = 'id' + Math.random().toString(16).slice(2);"
      class="btn btn-primary helpful" ></p>
  </button>
</li>
```

I want to know whether this code is correct (syntax). This is not working properly.

Comment: It's not. You should read a bit about HTML and JS

Comment: please just modify this if not correct. I tried a lot

Comment: what are you trying to achieve ?

Comment: I want to set unique id for button and p elements each time when code executes and access that id_btn1 via jquery

Comment: Maybe you should be asking about that instead then.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to build a list dynamically.
Here is a rough implementation using [React](http://facebook.github.io/react/index.html) (because it makes this really easy):

```
import React from 'react';
export class YourList extends React.Component {
  makeId() {
    return 'id' + Math.random().toString(16).slice(2);
  }
  renderItem() {
    return (
      <li>
        <a id={this.makeId()} className="btn btn-primary helpful">
          <i className="fa fa-thumbs-up"></i>
          Helpful
          <p id={this.makeId()} className="..."></p>
        </a>
      </li>
    );
  }
  render() {
    return <ul>{this.props.items.map(renderItem, this)}</ul>;
  }
}
```

And putting child elements into `<button>` is not a good idea, so I used an `<a>`; it looks like you are using [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#buttons) so it will work.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, let me try to understand what you want...

Here

```
<button id="javascript:var id_btn1 = 'id' + Math.random().toString(16).slice(2);">
```

You are trying to declare a variable named id_btn1 which contains the following value `Math.random().toString(16).slice(2);`. Ok supposing that it is possible (which it's not)... declaring a variable in a specific place doesn't mean that its value will be printed there.

What you should do is write the HTML elements without ids attributes:

```
<ul id="myList">
  <li>
    <button id="" class="btn btn-primary helpful">
      <i class="fa fa-thumbs-up"></i>
      Helpful
      <p id="" class="btn btn-primary helpful" ></p>
    </button>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Then select your list and generate an id value for every P and Button descendants. Like this:

```
function generateIds() {
    var list = document.getElementById('myList');
    var ps = list.getElementsByTagName("p");
    var btns = list.getElementsByTagName("button");

    for (var i = 0; i < ps.length; i++) {
        ps[i].setAttribute('id', Math.random().toString(16).slice(2));
    }

    for (var i = 0; i < btns.length; i++) {
         btns[i].setAttribute('id', Math.random().toString(16).slice(2));
    }
}
```

Then attach the `generateIds()` function to onload event of the `<body>` element:

```
<body onload="generateIds()">
```

Take a loot at this fiddle to it working http://jsfiddle.net/fnpo41pu/